# Xib not scaling on iPhone 6

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, size-classes, ios-autolayout

I have designed a xib whose configuration I have set as shown in the pic

[image]

I have added a UIImageView to the xib view and added proper constraints

[image]

So that the `UIImageView` appears full screen but the problem is that this works good for iPhone 5 but fails to scale on iPhone 6, I am not understanding the problem.

The `UIImageView` Configurations are as in the pic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fill the `UIImageView` full screen, set the `mode` to `Scale to fill`. If it does not fill screen yet, then the size of image is not appropriate. i would recommend you to use [vector graphics](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2016/09/vector-graphics-in-ios.html).

Comment: 1) Do you have same size of imageview and image? 2) Are you putting the 1x,2x,3x images in right dimension. 3) Try to use [vector graphics](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2016/09/vector-graphics-in-ios.html)

Comment: I am not adding any image I have just given a background colour to check how it is scaling and it is not scaling right

Comment: I am assuming that you are using the size classes. A weird issue with your image view. just hit and trial method:- delete and add new image view.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a silly mistake while adding the `UIView` as `subview` I was not describing the frame

Describing the frame as,

```
[self.profileView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Get_Bounds.width, Get_Bounds.height - 64)];
```

This does the trick.